# .NET WebClient.UploadValues vs WebClient.UploadData

Tags: .net, webclient

I am writing a class library to perform operations on a site outside my control.
The site is accepting form-posts as input.

Can anyone tell me if there is a difference between these two methods except the form of the data to upload?

```
    System.Net.WebClient.UploadData(Uri, Byte[]);

    System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(String, NameValueCollection);
```

I have no objections to arrange data either way, but started to wonder what the difference actually is, and it is still nagging me in some strange way, not knowing if there is a difference.

Comment: The source code to the framework is available - it's often a great way to answer this sort of question, and IME discover other useful things by accident while you're looking.

Comment: Thanks Will, I'm not Lazy, but I do tend to forget the obvious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both "POST" the data to the server.  If you use `UploadValues`, the values will be made available to the server in the `Request.Form` collection which is how a normal HTML form works.  `UploadData` gives you more flexibility since no escaping is performed on your data.  Its up to you to format the data in a way that the server will understand.  As a consequence of this, you can use `UploadData` to duplicate the behavior of `UploadValues`.

Comment: Thank you. that does make it for me :)