# In an Http Post request, what is the difference between submitting a form and sending content in the body

Tags: c#, http, http-post, webclient

I have been trying to debug an issue communicating with a web service, and it led me to a question. I was wondering what the difference between WebClient.UploadValues and WebClient.UploadData was in C#. I found the answer to that here [.NET WebClient.UploadValues vs WebClient.UploadData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539245/net-webclient-uploadvalues-vs-webclient-uploaddata)

The answer as essentially that UploadData submits content in the body of the request, where as UploadValues acts like submitting values from a form. I would have thought they were the same thing. When you submit content in the body of a post, it usually looks something like "key=value&key2=value2...". (when the content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

I thought they were the same thing until I noticed something. Using UploadValues gives me a totally different result than UploadData. In the case of the service I am communicating with, using UploadValues succeeds and UploadData returns the error "Request format is invalid".

So what exactly is the difference between a form post data and the content in the body of a request? Are they actually different things? Does an http request contain a querystring, body, AND form data?

Thanks!

**UPDATE** Okay, so I know what my problem was and I think I know the answer to most of my question.

Upload Values submits the body with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I am not entirely sure what content-type is used for UploadData by default, but you can set the header explicitly so it will take whatever you give it.

My original confusion arose when I was trying to do this by composing an HttpWebRequest and writing the content to the RequestStream. I was setting the Content Type too late. I guess it needs to be specified BEFORE writing to the Stream.

Form data is sent in the body of the request.

Comment: Post form data is sent in the body.  Are you sure the content type is the same for both functions?  (I'm guessing it will be different).

Comment: Im not really sure. As far as I know the WebClient methods determine that for you. I would assume for UploadValues it is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I have tried using an HttpWebRequest and writing to the body that way, explicitly setting the Content Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but I get the same result as UploadData.

Ill try to look for a better answer to that, though, and ill post it if I find it.

Comment: Okay, so I explicitly added the Content Type header to the WebClient and it acts the same as UploadValues. I haven't found any documentation as to what Content Type UploadData defaults too, though. I did a fiddler trace and it didn't have a Content Type specified. Not sure what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I know what my problem was and I think I know the answer to most of my question.

Upload Values submits the body with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I am not entirely sure what content-type is used for UploadData by default, but you can set the header explicitly so it will take whatever you give it.

My original confusion arose when I was trying to do this by composing an HttpWebRequest and writing the content to the RequestStream. I was setting the Content Type too late. I guess it needs to be specified BEFORE writing to the Stream.

Form data is sent in the body of the request.

Comment: Your guess is right, all servlet apis I've worked with expect you to specify headers before sending the body. When the Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded then the body basically contains a query string, a string that has the same format as query strings in urls (after the '?'), like: http://myhost/dir/cgi?key=val&key2=val2 but the application/x-www-form-urlencoded post has the advantage that the body is usually allowed to contain very large query strings while the header size and the path/query string of the request is always limited by web servers to a few or few ten KiloBytes.