# get slack channel history in .net web api

Tags: c#, slack-api

I have fetch channel history in my .Net Web API.
The slack reference https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history it states that we need to post the request.

Please if someone could help me with the code.

Part of Code I have implemented:

```
   #region create json payload to send to slack

        GetLatestMessage payload = new GetLatestMessage()
        {
            channel = "###",//value.channel_name,
            token = "############################"//added the token i have generated
            // user_name = value.user_name,
            //text = value.text
        };

      #endregion


        string payloadJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {

            NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection();
            data["payload"] = payloadJson;
            var response = client.UploadValues("https://slack.com/api/channels.history", "POST", data);


            //The response text is usually "ok"
           string responseText = _encoding.GetString(response);
           LogFileWriter("response=" + responseText);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free coding service where people do your job. Show some effort. What have you tried? What code does not work? Where are you having issues implementing your code?

Comment: @RononDex I had already tried my code.Added my code now.See if you could help.

Comment: Okay, now what part of your code does not work?

Comment: The response I get is: response={"ok":false,"error":"not_authed"} which means 'No authentication token provided.' but when I directly pass the same token in url (https://slack.com/api/channels.history?token=###&channel=####) i get proper json response with expected result.

Comment: Now thats a lot better, if you update your question with that information I am sure someone can help you

Comment: And now that you have down-voted my question no one will try to look over it! Not fair!!

Comment: Maybe try to show some effort from your side, explain your question better the next time. It is also not fair for us Stackoverflow users, coming across a question like yours and op getting mad when no one answers! We are human beeings, if you dont respect us dont expect to get respect in return...

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the issue I was facing.I was trying to sent the post json data in to Slack url. However The Slack Web API doesn't accept JSON data.Now when I post data using standard HTTP form attributes it accepts and returns proper response.

New code:

```
 var response = client.UploadValues("https://slack.com/api/channels.history", "POST", new NameValueCollection() {
{"token","###################"},
{"channel","######"}});

            //The response text is usually "ok"
           string responseText = _encoding.GetString(response);
           LogFileWriter("response=" + responseText);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
```

Comment: Good job. Glad you could fix it yourself :)

Comment: Very helpful, normal POST through client.UploadString with the same string of the GET params in POST body didnt work. this one works. I guess i did some error on encoding the data according to [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539245/net-webclient-uploadvalues-vs-webclient-uploaddata)